# git rebase not synchronize with remote?

Tags: git, rebase

I tried to squash minor bug fixes into one commit so I used

```
 git rebase -i 2afaw3f
```

now i have my local repo a bit cleaner but when I try to push this in hopes of making remote clean too it returns `Everything up-to-date`

and then checking if remote has been squashed too proves no.

How do I rebase my remote tree?

edit : and I pushed as

```
git push remote-name branch-name
```

hmm and how do I know about my remote configuration?

Comment: are you pushing the correct local to remote branch?

Comment: yes and the remote is hosted by beanstalkapp.com

Comment: if you tell something about your remotes config and how are you pushing, that could help you, me, and others reading this question :)

Comment: also double check you are not in a detached head state

Comment: What does `git status` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reset the remote branch to the commit *before* the base of your interactive rebase and push afterwards.

This is a technical solution - it is only save when you're the only one using the remote repository. If anyone else has already checked out the branch, then he will have trouble pushing his changesets.

A squashed rebase is a new commit:

```
A - B - C - D - E
                ^
              branch
```

after interactive rebase:

```
A - B - C - D - E
     \
       CDE
        ^
      branch
```

The commits C,D and E are not replaced but a new commit CDE is added to the repository and the branch is reset to that commit. Other users of the remote repository will still see "branch" on commit "E", may have added something to it and are unable to push.

So changing the history on a remote repository is never a good idea...